# debugging native code for child process in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb

I have an apk with package name a.b.c.d
The main process that gets launched when starting this app is a.b.c.d and it spawns a new process a.b.c.d.e
From android studio, I opened the apk in "Profile/debug apk" option. But, I'm only attach to process a.b.c.d and not to a.b.c.d.e
When I try to attach to the child process the error I get is below:

Starting LLDB server using code injection
Code injection has failed
Debugger detached

Process finished with exit code 0

Any tips on how I can get this working?